# Trouble raising -1 to a rational fraction-based power

Tags: c#, math, rational-number, fractions, exponent

On my TI-84 Plus (Silver Edition), I can enter the following without error: (-1)^(1/3) = -1
I also know that entering some expressions like the following would yield a non-real -imaginary- number like: (-1)^.5

Now, my problem is with C#'s Math object. If I send *any* fractions like these: `{1.667, 109.667, 0.667, 120.667} OR {4/3, 111/3, 2/3, 122/3}`, I would get: `{NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN}`.

Do I have to write a new object `MathHelper` that checks the rational value and returns an answer according to a limited input switch? Or is there a feature to the Math object I am missing. I can do this on the calculator...

*PS, I did not come across any similar questions online yet; so if this is a duplicate, please inform me ;)*

**[My new views]**
Thank you all for your help! I had finished upgrading the "Microsoft.Solver.Foundation.dll" to the 4.0 targeted framework and it turned out that the 'Rational' object seemed to return only -1's and 'Indeterminate'. Then after entering (-1)^(1/2) [nonreal ans] on Google, it dawned on me that I was working with nth-roots!! So, it turned out that I had already managed imaginary numbers in the past in C#, hence having solved my problem:

`Any even root 2n of a negative number -m will always equal an imaginary number i. (2n√-m)=i`
*I can't believe I forgot this simple algebra property*

Comment: Are you using `double` or `Rational`? Have you tried [`Rational.Power`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.rational.power%28v=vs.93%29.aspx)?

Comment: No, that's interesting - never heard of it before in C#. Let me take a look... Um, is it a feature that only come with the paid version or do I need to find it online?

Comment: There isn't a _free_ or _paid_ version of C# or the .NET Framework, there's only a free or paid version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @nneonneo I found the SolverFoundation online - no wonder I haven't yet heard of it. Now, I need to make it mesh with my 4.0 assemblies.
@ DaveZych Gotcha; Microsoft tends to make things a little confusing sometimes - I'll either misread or misinterpret their highlights sometimes...

Comment: of course, 0.667 != 2/3, and neither value can be exactly represented by a double.

Comment: @phoog 0.667 is a formated value: `String.Format("{0:00.000}", 2.0/3.0)'` in other words, this is the number I see in the output and not the debugger.

Comment: @ChristopherWalker yes, of course.  But my point holds if you use the in-memory binary format of the number.  You have more decimal places of precision (or, rather you have many binary places of precision), but you still cannot exactly represent 2/3 with a double.  Rather, you're representing something like 187649984473770 / 281474976710655.  This is much closer to 2/3 than 667/1000 is, but it's still not equal to it.

Comment: @phoog I see what your saying...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own Math helper to do functions like this (at least for `Math.Pow`). EDIT: Or you can use the `Rational` library like mentioned in the comments.

According to the documentation:

> Input: x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.
>
> Result: NaN

Review the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

Comment: I see in the docs it says: `{x = -1; y = NegativeInfinity or PositiveInfinity.} result = NaN` but my 'y' is definitely _not_ infinity...

Comment: @ChristoperWalker ... which means that this row in the table does not apply.  The one that *does* apply is the one Dave Zych cites.

Comment: @ChristopherWalker - like phoog states, the one I referenced is the one that applies to you. Your x is less than 0, and your y is not an integer.

Comment: Now, that I look over it again, I see what you mean. I guess I should continue upgrading SolverFoundation to Target Framework: 4.0... unless there is already one up to date?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, (-1)^R isn't defined for non-integer values of R.
If you try to calculate (-1)^(1/3), C# will calculate 1/3 first, resulting in a non-integer floating point number for R.

Solution:
Use the mathematical identity:

```
  a^(x/y) = a^x * a^(1/y)  x,y integers
```

For negative a, use:

```
 a^1/y = -(|a|^1/y)  // only works if y is odd
```

Or put together:

```
if (a < 0) {
  if (y % 2 = 1) {
    result = a^x * -1 * (-a)^(1.0/y);   // Replace ^ with the correct C# call.
  } else {
     // NaN
  }
} else {
  result = a^(x/y);
}
```

Comment: I tested this out and it only returned 1's for all powers. I then reviewed over the math and noticed that your ((-a)^(1.0/y)) where a = -1 would always yield a 1. I fixed this by eliminating both this and -1.